What does index nil mean?
I attempted to mess around with the children because I think that's the problem but I was unsuccessful
local tycoon = script.Parent.Parent

local mainItems = tycoon:FindFirstChild("MainItems")
local values = tycoon:FindFirstChild("Values")

mainItems.OwnerDoor.Door.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if values.OwnerValue.Value == nil then
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
        if player  then
            if player:FindFirstChild("HasTycoon").Value == false then
                values.OwnerValue.Value = player
            end
        end
    end 
end)


It means you tried to access a child or property of a value that is nil. Post your full error message please.

10:52:56.036  Workspace.Tycoons.Tycoon.Scripts.Core:7: attempt to index nil with 'OwnerValue'  -  Server - Core:7

The problem is that your values is nil then. Because there is no child Values apparently.

Do any of these existing questions help solve your problem?

A nil value or just nil is Lua's symbol for "no value".

Workspace.Tycoons.Tycoon.Scripts.Core:7: attempt to index nil with
'OwnerValue'

The error tells you that you tried to index a nil value with 'OwnerValue' in Line 7.
if values.OwnerValue.Value == nil then

The indexing operation is values.OwnerValue. So we know value is nil..
Indexing nil doesn't make any sense. Hence it is not allowed. How would you index nothing?
Find out why values is nil and fix that.
